# Program can't find suitable begin function in nested range-based for loop without using auto

Tags: c++, c++11

So I'm reading C++ Primer, and I arrive at exercise 3.43 in which I'm supposed to make a program that prints all the elements in an array *without using auto* - I'm pretty sure this kinda goes against the point of using a range-based for loop, but I think the goal is to understand and learn to explicitly declare confusing variables such as pointers and references. So I write the program:

```
#include <iostream>

char ia[3][4] = {{'q', 'w', 'e', 'r'}, {'t', 'y', 'u', 'i'}, {'o', 'p', 'a', 's'}};

int main ()
{
    for (char &row : *ia)
        for (char &col : &row)
            std::cout << col << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But even thought the first for loop seems fine, the second, innermost loop claims there is no suitable begin declaration and the program won't compile. Why?

I'm still new to range-based for loops, but if my understanding is correct: I need to pass `row` and `col` as references so they don't get automatically converted to pointers by the compiler because that's how arrays work (how quirky!), and similarly since `ia` would be passed as a pointer to its first element I need to dereference it so it gets passed as the actual element of the array (which is another array since that's how multidimensional arrays work).

That way I'm essentially telling the program: for every row in the array, go through this column, and for every column, (since each column contains one element) print this column.

But the program still insists:

> "begin was not declared for this scope."

Is there something wrong with my declarations?

Comment: (1) Use `ia` instead of `*ia` in the first loop, (2) use `auto const &` instead of `char &` in both loops.

Comment: @wohlstad read the question carefully, it says without using auto

Comment: Missed that. Posted an answer without `auto`.

Comment: This is a piece of code just screaming out for `std::array`.

Comment: "*so [`row` and `col`] don't get automatically converted to pointers by the compiler because that's how arrays work*" - not always. Fixed arrays decay into pointers only in certain contexts. "*since `ia` would be passed as a pointer to its first element*" - not in this case, it wouldn't. A `range-for` loop allows a fixed array as input, there is no array-to-pointer decay performed at the call site (the loop will use that internally while iterating the array).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The problem:**

There are 2 issues in your code, both in the first loop:

1. The whole 2D array is `ia` not `*ia`.
2. The type of the ranged loop element is `char[4]`.

**A fixed version:**

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char ia[3][4] = { {'q', 'w', 'e', 'r'}, {'t', 'y', 'u', 'i'}, {'o', 'p', 'a', 's'} };

    using CharArr4 = char[4];
    for (CharArr4 const& row : ia) 
    {
        for (char const& col : row) 
        {
            std::cout << col << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Notes:**

1. I used a `using` statement to define the `char[4]` type to make it more readable.
2. I used `const` for the types of the elements of the loop since you do not modify them.
3. There's no reason for `ia` to be global (although in this case it can work as well).

**Output:**

```
q
w
e
r
t
y
u
i
o
p
a
s
```

[**Live demo - Godbolt**](https://godbolt.org/z/TjsjcGjKb)

---

Update:
As @RemyLebeau commented, if you are not allowed to use `using` as well, here's the version for the first loop without it:

```
for (char(& row)[4] : ia)
```

Comment: And without the `using` and `const`: `for (char (&row)[4] : ia) { for (char col : row) { ... } }`

Comment: @RemyLebeau do you see any advantage in that over my suggestion ?

Comment: If they are not allowed to use `auto`, they probably are not allowed to use `using` either

Comment: Might be. Added an update with this version. Thanks !